# Array being pushed into another array isn't displaying

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make 6 random RGB colors, So I have 2 loops, inner one is only going to repeat 3 times because I want 3 numbers, outer one will repeat 6 times because I want 6 colors. When I push my small array on 3 random numbers onto a big array, its pushing the last array instead of the first 5.

```
let colorArray = []

makeSixColors();

function makeSixColors() { //Making 6 random color RGBS
    let tempArray = []; //storing rgbs in an array, then storing that in an array

    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            tempArray[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
        }
        colorArray.push(tempArray)
        console.log(colorArray[j])
    }
    console.log(colorArray)
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
(3) [65, 202, 231]

(3) [15, 147, 151]

(3) [225, 123, 121]

(3) [247, 17, 107]

(3) [144, 225, 191]

(3) [188, 61, 122] //My 6 small arrays



(6) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]

0: (3) [188, 61, 122]

1: (3) [188, 61, 122]

2: (3) [188, 61, 122]

3: (3) [188, 61, 122]

4: (3) [188, 61, 122]

5: (3) [188, 61, 122] //The big Array im pushing on.. Why only the last array???
```

Comment: Are you trying to push the whole `tempArray` as element or just the element of `tempArray` in `colorArray `?

Comment: It's happening because you keep modifying `tempArray`, to which all elements of `colorArray` are references. I can't test this now, but if you move `let tempArray = [];` inside the outer `for` loop I think this will work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

When you append `tempArray` to `colorArray` here:

```
colorArray.push(tempArray)
```

This doesn't add a *copy* of `tempArray` to `colorArray`; it adds a *reference* to `tempArray` to `colorArray`. This means that if the elements of this `tempArray` are later changed, the array inside `colorArray` will change as well, since they are the same array.

So, in your loop, you are adding a reference to the same array to `colorArray` six times, which is why all six elements of `colorArray` are the same.

You can fix this by moving `let tempArray = []` inside of your `for` loop, so that it creates a new array to add to `colorArray` every time.

Comment: Thanks, instead of that I just destructured the tempArray into the colorArray.

Answer (score 1):

After you pushed `tempArray` in your `colorArray`, you changed it. `colorArray` only contains a reference to `tempArray`, so every element inside of `colorArray` is the same in the end.

How to fix it:

Declare `tempArray` inside of your outer `for` loop so you have a new instance with each iteration:

```
function makeSixColors() { 

    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

        let tempArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            tempArray[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
        }

        colorArray.push(tempArray)
        console.log(colorArray[j])
    }

    console.log(colorArray)
}
```

By the way, you should multiply `Math.random()` with 256 instead of 255, otherwise you exclude 255.

Comment: Yea, makes a lot sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the concat function,like this:
`var newArray = colorArray.concat(tempArray)`